# Conjecture: $\forall n \geq n_0\exists k \geq 0: \gcd(2^k-1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}) = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, perfect-powers

**Context & Interest.**

See this MSE post about a [twin-prime related topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4874874/26327).  Basically $0$ is a easily seen to be a generic point in this topology. Every generic point is clearly dense as a singleton subset, meaning its closure is the whole space $\Bbb{Z}/p_n\#$. In an approach toward potentially proving the twin prime conjecture, I must show that the interval of residues $I = [1, \dots, p_{n+1}^2 - 2]$ is such that its set of elementwise powers $\mathcal{I} = \{ x^k : x \in I, k \geq 0\}$ is also dense in $(\Bbb{Z}, \tau)$. But because $x = 2,3$ are such that $x^2 \neq 1 \pmod q$ for all $q\geq 5$, we get reduction to the below question.  Or in other words the conjecture below is sufficient to prove density of $\mathcal{I}$.

> **Conjecture.** For all sufficiently large $n$ (something like $n \geq 3$); either $\exists k \geq 2$ such that $\gcd(2^k - 1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}) = 1$, *or* $\exists k \geq 2$ such that $\gcd(3^k - 1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}) = 1$, or both.

Where $p_n\# := p_{n}p_{n-1} \cdots p_1$ is primorial.

**Question.**
How can we prove this conjecture easily (intuitively it looks like an easy problem)?

**Attempt.**  Working each possibility in the either/or individually, take the first one.

Then we want to show that $2^k - 1$ is a solution to:

$$
X(X-2)\cdots (X-(q - 2)) = 0 \pmod {q}, \\
\forall\text{ prime } q \mid p_n\#
$$

for some $k \geq 0$.  But this seems more hopeless than the original formulation!

Comment: Please provide *context* when posting your *many* conjectures. In particular please provide evidence supporting your belief that the conjecture is true (and also why it is of interest). Mathematicians usually don't publicize conjecture without strong evidence (and motivation).

Comment: Context should be posted in the question, not in coimments,

Comment: @JohnOmielan oops I meant $k \geq 2$!

Comment: Wondering if this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/424222/26327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your conjecture is true. In particular, for any $n\ge 3$, then $\exists\, k \geq 3$ such that $\gcd(2^k - 1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}) = 1$, *and* $\exists\, k \geq 3$ such that $\gcd(3^k - 1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}) = 1$. In particular, this occurs with any prime $k$ where $2k + 1 \gt p_n$. First, for $2^k - 1$, for any prime $p \mid 2^k - 1$, then

$$2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

With the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order), we get

$$m = \operatorname{ord}_{p}(2) \;\;\to\;\; m \mid k$$

Since $k$ is prime, this means that $m = 1$ or $m = k$. As $m = 1$ doesn't work, this means that $m = k$. However, by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), we then get for some positive, even integer $j$ that

$$k \mid \varphi(p) \;\to\; p - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{k} \;\to\; p = jk + 1 \;\to\; p \ge 2k + 1 \gt p_n$$

As this applies to *all* prime factors of $2^k - 1$, we then get

$$\gcd\left(2^k - 1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}\right) = 1$$

A similar argument shows that $\gcd(3^k - 1, \frac{p_n\#}{6}) = 1$.

More generally, $k$ can have up to $1$ factor of $2$ (since then the multiplicative order $m$ of any prime $p \mid a^k$ where $a\in\{2,3\}$ can possibly have a factor of $2$ but, since $2^2 - 1 = 3$ and $3^2 - 1 = 8$, then $m$ is not $2$, so it *needs* to have at least one odd prime factor of $k$) and *every* odd prime factor $p$ has $2p + 1 \gt p_n$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152191/discussion-on-answer-by-john-omielan-conjecture-forall-n-geq-n-0-exists-k-g); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.